# C# - Get NamedRanges of a particular sheet in Excel using Oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Using Oledb, is it possible to get all NamedRanges of a particula sheet in Excel?

I have written following code which gives me NamedRanges but I am not able to figure out to which sheet does the NamedRange refer to.

```
private String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFilePath)
{
    OleDbConnection objConn = null;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

    try
    {
        //String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0", excelFilePath);
        objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        objConn.Open();

        // Get the data table containg the schema guid.
        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info, null);

        if (dt == null)
            return null;

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;

        // Add the sheet name to the string array.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            excelSheets[i++] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        return excelSheets;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up.
        if (objConn != null)
        {
            objConn.Close();
            objConn.Dispose();
        }
        if (dt != null)
        {
            dt.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you need [Open XML Sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for such an endeavour. That way you can access the name manager dynamically. Otherwise with OleDb you can get values out of the sheet only if you knew your named ranges beforehand.

Comment: @andrei.ciprian: Thanks for your reply. I am leaving idea to read named ranges by sheet name. Do you think it is possible to read description of a named range using Oledb or LinqToExcel package? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Open XML SDK fan. The solution is straightforward. This returns both workbook and sheet scoped named ranges, on the left there's the Excel name manager definitions, 2 sheets with 2 named ranges in each sheet, on the right a sample run.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg294173%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

[image]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The procedure examines the workbook that you specify, 
    /// looking for the part that contains defined names. 
    /// If it exists, the procedure iterates through all the 
    /// contents of the part, adding the name and value for 
    /// each defined name to the returned dictionary
    /// </summary>
    public static IDictionary<String, String> XLGetDefinedNames(String fileName)
    {
      var returnValue = new Dictionary<String, String>();
      //
      using (SpreadsheetDocument document = 
          SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
      {
        var wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        //
        DefinedNames definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.DefinedNames;
        if (definedNames != null)
        {
          foreach (DefinedName dn in definedNames)
            returnValue.Add(dn.Name.Value, dn.Text);
        }
      }
      //
      return returnValue;
    }
```